# json_encode utf-8

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, json

i want to know why json_encode echo "null" and i use spanish characters as "ñ"

```
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","josilandia","*****");
mysql_select_db("critica",$link);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
$region="Mosel-Saar-Ruwer";

$resultado=mysql_query("SELECT marcavino,comentario,estrellas FROM recomendacion2
 WHERE region='$region'");

$recomendacion=array();   
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
   $lamarcavino =utf8_decode($row['marcavino']);
   $elcomentario =utf8_decode($row['comentario']);

   $laestrella = $row['estrellas'];
   $arr=array('marcavino'=>"$lamarcavino",'comentario'=>"$elcomentario",'estrellas'=>"$laestrella");
     $recomendacion[]= $arr;

  print(json_encode($recomendacion));
```

Answer (score 1):

`$lamarcavino` is ISO 8859-1 after the `utf8_decode()`, because `utf8_decode()` [converts from UTF-8 to ISO 8859-1](http://php.net/utf8_decode).

`json_encode()` [does only support UTF-8](http://php.net/json_encode) and some of the higher characters in ISO 8859-1 are invalid in UTF-8.

Comment: but mb_detect_encoding display UTF-8

Comment: 1. It should be called `mb_guess_encoding()`. 2. At least set the third parameter to true. 3. On my system it always says `UTF-8`, regardless of what I feed in. 4. Have you seen what charsets it *can* actually detect (`mb_detect_order()`)?

Comment: i solved but i forgot to mention that an android application read the script

Comment: the problem was in the array $arr  $arr= array('marcavino'=>utf8_encode("$lamarcavino"),'comentario'=>utf8_encode("$elcomentario"),'estrellas'=>"$laestrella");

Comment: You could also just remove the utf8_decode. The way you implemented it now you'll lose all characters not in ISO 8859-1.